# Why json permission is denied in the user of the linux

Tags: php, json, laravel, ubuntu

The problem behind the laravel installation in ubuntu 18.04

[ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you should open up a terminal and type this command:

```
sudo chown -R user ~/.composer
```

with the user being your current user, in your case, dilip34

After you have ran this command, you should have permission to run your composer global require command.

Comment: Select the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

As the error specify you do not have permission.

To resolve this error execute this command

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer
```

You may also need to remove the `.composer` file from the current directory, to do this open up a terminal window and type this command

```
sudo rm -rf .composer
```

**OR**

If that does not work then try to change the permission of `composer.lock` file

```
sudo chown -R $USER composer.lock
```

**OR**

Check the directory you are working in